# Passing files browsed as argument

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an upload button and four file upload controls linked to this single button.  In the `onbutton` click event I'm trying to run JavaScript code.  Is there any way I can get the number of files browsed and pass them as an argument in my JavaScript function?

Answer (score 0):

Your file upload controls are pretty much like regular input fields. You can access them by ID in javascript and retrieve their `value` and check whether or not it's an empty string

Comment: except they could be decorated - so keep that into account (you might have to inspect the source on the browser)